# Timestamp conversion in to Date format giving me Wrong date In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, unix-timestamp, date-conversion

In my application, A user from US created a offer on 30th November 2020, while getting the search response in UI, I am getting created timestamp as 1606786157.343  ,When I am converting in to date format its returning me 1st Dec 2020 even in UTC format.

I tried this solution - moment.unix(1606786157.343).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY")

How should I convert so that I can get exact 30th November 2020 in Indian or US timezone?

Please help

Comment: you need to make sure your backend is saving the right time. when u save 1606786157.343 as a float, then you gonna get the wrong time. The server should be the source of truth, the place that synchronises the correct time. Most cases, it should be reconverted to local time of the server, before you save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the moment.unix() constructor to accept the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch. Then we can use moment-timezone to convert to other timezones:

```js
const timeUtc = moment.unix(1606786157.343).utc();

console.log("US Time (New York):", timeUtc.tz("America/New_York").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
console.log("US Time (LA):", timeUtc.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
console.log("US Time (Chicago):", timeUtc.tz("America/Chicago").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
console.log("India Time:", timeUtc.tz("Asia/Kolkata").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

Comment: In Indian Time zone its returning 12/01/2020 06:59:17 , can't it be constant that is 30th Nov 2020 which is original created date, irrespective of timezone ?

Comment: Well, the original date is 1606786157.343, which corresponds to a time of 12/01/2020 01:29:17 UTC. Which is going to be the 30th of November in all US timezones, so that pretty much makes sense! We can see this would be 30/11/2020 20:29 in New York and 30/11/2020 17:29 in LA. And of course, it will be 12/01/2020 06:59:17 in Indian time.